# Hibernate generated select statement has two ids, entity id value populated with a null on load

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

We have Hibernate Interceptor (extending EmptyInterceptor) that loads Spring classes on instantiate based on the incoming entityName:

```
@Override
public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id) {
    Object bean = null;
    String className = entityName.substring(entityName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    StringBuffer entity = new StringBuffer(className.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase());
    entity.append(className.substring(1));
    String beanName = entity.toString();
            // Place any modified bean names here
    if ("policyType".equalsIgnoreCase(entity.toString())) {
        beanName = "policyTypeEntity";
    }

    if (this.applicationContext.containsBean(beanName)) {
        bean = this.applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    }
    return bean;
}
```

Based on this setup, when a createCriteria query is run,

```
this.policyInfo = (PolicyInfo) session.createCriteria(PolicyInfo.class).createAlias("quote", "q").add(Restrictions.eq("q.id", quoteId)).uniqueResult();
```

Hibernate is generating all SQL (abridged) as below (This is just one of the sub queries that is eagerly initialized):

```
 /* load one-to-many com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans.PolicyInfo.persons */ select
    persons0_.POLICY_INFO_ID as POLICY_I5_35_1_,
    persons0_.ID as ID1_27_1_,
    persons0_.ID as ID1_27_0_,
    persons0_.WORK_ADDRESS_ID as WORK_ADD2_27_0_,
    persons0_.HOME_ADDRESS_ID as HOME_ADD3_27_0_,
    persons0_.MAIL_ADDRESS_ID as MAIL_ADD4_27_0_,
    persons0_.POLICY_INFO_ID as POLICY_I5_27_0_,
    persons0_.HOMEOWNER_VERIFIED as HOMEOWN26_27_0_ 
from
    COMBO21_OWNER.PERSON_INFO persons0_ 
where
    persons0_.POLICY_INFO_ID=?
```

If you notice, the ID column is repeated twice, resulting in the actual class property being set to null.

Here's how the beginning of PersonInfo entity looks like:
    package com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans;

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PersonInfo extends DomainObject implements Comparable<PersonInfo> {
private Address workAddress;
private Address homeAddress;
private Address mailAddress;
private PolicyInfo policyInfo;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private String titlePrefix;
private String priorLastName;
private String ssn;
private Date birthDate;
private String ethnicGroup;
private String language;
and so on...
```

This inherits the DomainObject which looks like below:
    package com.ipacc.onelink.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DomainObject implements Serializable {
protected Integer id;

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Adding the abridged mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans.PersonInfo" table="PERSON_INFO" schema="COMBO21_OWNER" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
        <column name="ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">PERSON_INFO_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="workAddress" class="com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans.Address" fetch="select"
        cascade="all">
        <column name="WORK_ADDRESS_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks

**Update:**
I flattened the classes to push down the id column and removed the DomainObject as mentioned above but have still not made any progress. So we can rule out an issue with the the Hibernate inheritance mapping strategy (as I do not use an ancestor class any more).
I also tried this on Hibernate 4.2.7.SP1, so I can confirm it was an issue in previous revision too. I do not believe this is an Hibernate issue, but an issue with the handshake between Spring and Hibernate when using the instantiate interceptor.

Here's the duplicate IDs I am getting:
    Hibernate: 
    /* load one-to-many com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans.PolicyInfo.installments */ select
        installmen0_.POLICY_INFO_ID as POLICY_I2_35_1_,
        installmen0_.ID as ID1_18_1_,
        installmen0_.ID as ID1_18_0_,
        installmen0_.POLICY_INFO_ID as POLICY_I2_18_0_,
    Hibernate: 
    /* load one-to-many com.ipacc.onelink.model.entitybeans.PolicyInfo.policyQuestionAnswers */ select
        policyques0_.POLICY_INFO_ID as POLICY_I2_35_2_,
        policyques0_.ID as ID1_37_2_,
        policyques0_.ID as ID1_37_1_,

Has anyone used Hibernate EmptyInterceptor's instantiate method to instantiate Spring beans and had success?

Comment: Is there any threading issue during initializing Hibernate Session and Spring context creation=. Furthermore provide your Person entity pls.

Comment: Do not see any exceptions with threading during Hibernate Session or Spring Context creation. I have updated the original to include the abridged version of entity information.

Comment: Where are all the mapping annotations of your entity?

Comment: JB, I have added the abridged mapping info from the hbm.xml file.

Comment: Do you perform your query using different hibernate sessions in parallel. Could be some hibernate caching issue in this case. In one thread the person entity is already attached to session and in the other it is not. No exception must be thrown in this case.

Comment: No it is just one session and all the related entities are eagerly initialized using Hibernate.initialize as below:
Hibernate.initialize(policyInfo.getPersons());                      The issue is not just this one entity, but all the loaded have their ids set to null.

Comment: Just added a answer concerning Hibernate Inheritance strategies.

Comment: I tried the changes as you mentioned to no avail. Even with a flattened structure I still get the same SQLs with duplicate ids

Comment: Hmm. Ok then i would suggest to test your hibernate config, the mappiing and the query without the spring interception to break down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mapping problem within your PersonInfo class.
You have 3 different address associations.  This is in my point of view a database design issue. The foreign key assocation should be in this case managed by the Address class or entity. Check how this association is implemented.

Additionally PersonInfo has an association to its own. Recusrive dependency.

```
public class PersonInfo extends DomainObject implements Comparable<PersonInfo> {
   private Address workAddress;
   private Address homeAddress;
   private Address mailAddress;
   private PolicyInfo policyInfo;
```

So check if the mapping could be a problem and if not check if Spring is able to resolve
that kind of recursive dependencies with interceptor mechanism. I don't know but this could be a problem.

Try to simplify your PersonInfo mapping and check if it works than in proper way with Spring and the Interceptor mechanism.

Comment: This is not just an issue with PersonInfo, it is an issue with all the entities that are being loaded from the database on the load. So we can rule out this as mapping problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a possible answer. You don't provide an inheritence strategy for your 
DomainObject and PersonInfo association.

Check for Inheritance Strategies and their requironments. Seems that your PersonInfo class
needs in the case of default inheritance strategy an additionally Id property.

Following strategies exist

- Table per Class Hierarchy
- Table per Class
- Table per concrete Class

I think your mapping does not provide any inheritance strategy definitions.
Additionally you can do that kind of inheritance with annotation based mapping.
But you use xml mappings and there it seems to me that you don't define that association.

Additionally i think you try to resolve this inheritance dependency with the recursive dependency to a PersonInfo reference. But this is just an assumption.

So this should be the reaseon why there are two ids. One id for the DomainObject Table and one id for the PersonInfo table. Check if you have an DomainObject with a foreignkey constraint to PersonInfo or check your inheritance strategy.

Comment: There is no DomainObject table. I am using Table per concrete class using implicit polymorphism strategy. So this should be fine, correct?

Comment: You need to specify a mapping for domainobject and PersonInfo class in the case of table per concrete class. Additionaly you need the id property in the mapping of the subclasses as well as any other derived property. Here is a nice tutorial which describes the different strategies with examples: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping/

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. Since I am using Spring to inject beans while instantiation, does this really matter? The intention of creating the DomainObject class is to centralize the id column as common to all entity objects and to declare each entity as Serializable. It is not the intention to store DomainObject as a table.

Comment: I dont think that it is a spring problem. Try to adapt your mapping by adding the DomainObject class to hbm. Than hibernate creates the addional table DomainObject which is necessary in the case of table p. Concrete class. Pls tell me if the resulting hibernate query also contains to person_ids. Should be. One mapped for DomainObject table and one for PersonInfo

Comment: Each entity object (that derives from the DomainObject class) has its own sequence as generator class. So if I were to create a new DomainObject.hbm.xml, what would the generator class be for this? Also, which table would it refer to when there is no physical table that represents this?

Comment: You just need to declare the person_id within the DomainObject class but within the mapping file you need to declare it for all classes which derive from DomainInfo. The declaration (mapping) must be identical within all mappings. The generator also. If you choose this strazegy then a DomainTsble must exist and can be creazed automatically by hibrrnate if not present.

Comment: I would suggest to simplyfi your mapping and removr the inheritanc, since you have just the id propety in your baseclass. Another solution is to change your strategy to "table per class".

Comment: Since DomainObject class is common ancestor for all entity objects, I cannot declare person_id in the DomainObject; also the generators of the ID property are separate Sequences in the Oracle for each entity.Yes, I think I will need to simplify by removing the inheritance as the other option you suggested may not work due to the subclasses having NOT NULL properties. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: So given that I am not using inheritance anymore for my entity classes, why would I still be facing the same issue?
All my ID properties are populated with null values. Any clues?